# LG-P870 USB not detected in Windows 7

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode

I'm trying to connect my LG-P870 to my laptop running Windows 7, so I can drop some music and contacts onto it. My software version is P87010i.

I installed the USB driver (tried two versions) as recommended, but still no luck. I keep seing a reference to the Tools menu and Mass Storage selection but I can't find any Tools menu on my phone. I can find the Settings menu, but no Tools.

Why can't I simply plug my phone in and see it in Explorer? It charges fine with the usb, just no comm.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no Tools in Android. What is this reference you are talking about? Can you post the link?

Comment: Have you checked if your USB connection *on the phone* is set to the correct mode (most likely MTP), and not e.g. to "charge only" (the default at least with the P880)? What you mean by "tools menu", from this context, most likely is what I'm referring to as well: When connected to USB, open the notification area and tap the "USB connection" entry. There you can select the connection mode.